# Как доделать список выпадающих городов на PHP

Tags: php, select

Есть список выпадающих стран, к нему подключен рукописный ввод городов. Как реализовать список городов с привязкой к странам?
Фрагмент файла config.php-------------------------->
    `'countries' => array(
                    'AF' => __('Afghanistan', 'lovestory'),
                    'AL' => __('Albania', 'lovestory'),
                    'DZ' => __('Algeria', 'lovestory'),
                    'AS' => __('American Samoa', 'lovestory'),
                    'AD' => __('Andorra', 'lovestory'),
                    'AO' => __('Angola', 'lovestory'),
                    'AI' => __('Anguilla', 'lovestory'),
                    'AQ' => __('Antarctica', 'lovestory'),
                    'AG' => __('Antigua And Barbuda', 'lovestory'),),`

```
<?php if(!ThemexCore::checkOption('user_location')) { ?> <tr> <th><?php _e('Country', 'lovestory'); ?></th> <td> <div class="select-field"> <span></span> <?php echo ThemexInterface::renderOption(array( 'id' => 'country', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => array_merge(array('0' => '&ndash;'), ThemexCore::$components['countries']), 'value' => !empty(ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']['country'])?ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']['country']:null, 'wrap' => false, )); ?></div> </td>

</tr> <tr> <th><?php _e('City', 'lovestory'); ?></th> <td> <div class="field-wrap"> <input type="text" name="city" size="50" value="<?php echo ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']['city']; ?>" /> </div> </td>

<?php if(!ThemexCore::checkOption('user_location')) { ?> <tr> <td><h5><?php _e('Country', 'lovestory'); ?></h5></td> <td> <div class="select-field"> <span></span> <?php echo ThemexInterface::renderOption(array( 'id' => 'country', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => array_merge(array('0' => '&ndash;'), ThemexCore::$components['countries']), 'value' => isset($_GET['country'])?$_GET['country']:null, 'attributes' => array('class' => 'countries-list'), 'wrap' => false, )); ?></div></td></tr>

</div></td></tr><tr> <td><h5><?php _e('City', 'lovestory'); ?></h5></td> <td> <div class="select-field"> <span></span> <?php echo ThemexInterface::renderOption(array( 'id' => 'city', 'type' => 'select_city', 'value' => isset($_GET['city'])?$_GET['city']:'', 'attributes' => array( 'class' => 'filterable-list', 'data-filter' => 'countries-list', ), 'wrap' => false, )); ?>
```

Comment: Это файл profile.php

Comment: Всю информацию, касающиеся вопроса, вносите в сам вопрос.

Comment: Нажмите править под вопросом, и добавьте всю информацию в сам вопрос, а не в комментарии.